# The group of the modular automorphisms of the Shimura curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, shimura-varieties

Let $B$ be a rational indefinite division quaternion algebra, $(X,G)$ the Shimura datum associated with $B$ (i.e., $X$ is the upper half plane and $G(R) = (B \otimes_\mathbb{Q} R)^*$ for a ring $R/\mathbb{Q}$), $K$ an open compact subgroup of $B \otimes \mathbb{A}_f$, and let $\operatorname{Sh}_K = G(\mathbb{Q}) \backslash X \times G(\mathbb{A}_f) / K$ be the Shimura curve associated with $B$ of level $K$.
Let $N(K)$ be the normalizer of $K$ in $B \otimes \mathbb{A}_f$.

For $\beta \in N(K)$ let $\rho(\beta) \colon \operatorname{Sh}_K \to \operatorname{Sh}_K$ be the automorphism defined by $(x, g) \mapsto (x, g\beta)$.

In Definition 1.1 of de Vera-Piquero's "The Shimura covering of a Shimura curve: automorphisms and étale subcoverings", he calls an automorphism of the form $\rho(\beta)$ for some $\beta \in N(K)$ modular, and defines $\operatorname{Aut}^{\operatorname{mod}} \operatorname{Sh}_K$ as the group of the modular automorphisms.

By definition $N(K)$ surjects onto $\operatorname{Aut}^{\operatorname{mod}} \operatorname{Sh}_K$ by the map $\rho$.
In the paragraph above Definition 1.1 of the paper, he claims (without proofs) that

> the kernel of $\rho$ is $Z(\mathbb{Q}) K = \mathbb{Q}^* K$, where $Z(\mathbb{Q})$ is the center of $G(\mathbb{Q})$.

How can we show it?

It seems that this also holds for more general Shimura data $(G,X)$, for example, for those who satisfy the following property:

(A) the kernel of the canonical map $G(\mathbb{R}) \to \operatorname{Aut} X$ is the center of $G(\mathbb{R})$.

(I could show that many Shimura data, for example the PEL Shimura data associated with totally indefinite quaternion algebras over totally real number fields satisfy the property (A),
and hence it seems that these Shimura data satisfy the highlighted statement.)

(I don't know whether the statement (A) holds for general Shimura data or not, nor whether the statement (A) is well-known or not.)